# Color plot depending on value but for multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I need to create a plot from a data frame that contains data from multiple files.  Some of the files are labelled as `reference` and some as `user`. I want to have smooth lines for each file, but the coloring should be done by label. Here is some test data for testing:

```
test <- data.frame(
  y = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5),
  x = rep(c(1, 2), 4),
  label = c("ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "user", "user", "user", "user"),
  file = as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
)
```

My current make-shift solution is to use `shape=file`:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, shape=file)) +
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_line() +  
  guides(shape=FALSE)
```

[image: Result]
But I wonder whether there is a solution that does not rely on the shape, because I ideally want them to be the same. I already looked at the following questions, but they were all not helpful for my case:

- [Assign color to lines ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681848/assign-color-to-lines-ggplot2)
- [How do I have multiple lines of the same color with GG Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976114/how-do-i-have-multiple-lines-of-the-same-color-with-gg-plot)
- [Changing line colors with ggplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171263/changing-line-colors-with-ggplot)

Comment: try `geom_line(aes(group=file))`

Comment: What is exactly "a better solution"? I guess a clear criterion is needed.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Thank you, this worked perfectly fine. You can write a full answer and I will accept it, so that others can find the solution more quickly.

Comment: @YHJang I will update my question and will be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_line` uses the `group` aesthetic to decide which points should be linked.  So you can use:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, group=file)) +
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Your previous solution using `shape` worked because if `group` is absent `ggplot` uses the combinations of other discrete factors already specified (shape, fill, colour etc) as grouping factors.